# What is the difference between db.open and db.connect?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my adventure of making a NodeJS HTTP server, I began with the code below. This server is supposed to be able to handle around 10,000 requests all occurring within the same second or two.

I was wondering what exactly is the difference between `db.open` and `db.connect`. The [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html) says "initialize DB connection" and "connect to DB" respectively, but this seems to be the same thing to me. Further more, they both use `db.close()` to close the connection. Is there one I should be using?

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

     req.on('data', function(chunk) {
          //Do some stuff here
     });

     req.on('end', function() {
          //Do some stuff here
          var db = new Db('test', new Server("111.111.11.111", 27017,{auto_reconnect: false}), {safe: true});  

          db.open(function(err, db) {
               //Insert data into DB
               db.close();
          });
     });
}); //End Http server
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all try to take out your database connection out from requests and keep it 1 per app. Mashing database with 10k connections when all clients wants to end their request is not a good idea. As far as I remember database have limited connection pool so this is the reason of yours bottleneck and errors. Unfortunately I cannot give right now good example for this one.

And as to "`db.connect`" and "`db.open`" difference is mostly in code usage. To be more precise here is [connect](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#connect) and also [open](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#open) and as you can see connect is using connection string where open uses `new DB` which needs `new Server` declared to work.

Oh and one more thing, try to use higher level library for mongoDB connection such as mongoose (I cannot paste link in "nice way" so here it is: mongoosejs.com)

Comment: Just a couple of things I want to say. I'm not having any errors and my server works fine. I just want to know the difference between open and connect in a general sense. In my specific case, I linked the docs above and you linked me to MongoClient, which I am not using. Do your ideas transfer over to my situation? Lastly, I need my app to handle more than 1 request as a time. As I stated already, this server works fine, and what I am truly seeking for is a more efficient server handling DB open / close / connect if possible.

Comment: @krikara What @necromos is saying here is critically important for a scalable server.  The connection you're opening is actually a connection _pool_ that's designed to be left open open for the life of the app and shared by all requests.  You can size it however big you need for the concurrency you're looking for.  So use `MongoClient.connect` during your app start up as the old style of `db.open` / `db.connect` is somewhat confusing, as you've found.

Comment: @JohnnyHK In my other post, I found that MongoClient.connect is slower. Ideally, I am trying to maximize efficiency and trying to find the fastest way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485281/nodejs-http-server-handling-multiple-requests-inserting-into-db

Comment: @krikara I saw that, but it doesn't matter because you should only be calling that once, during start up.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Everytime I call it once, it either slows down a lot, sometimes causing connection errors (depending on the db/MongoClient method). How can I enlarge the connection pool or create multiple and use them efficiently?

Comment: @krikara See my answer in your other post.

Comment: @JohnyHK thank you for comment on this case and yes this is what I had on my mind. @kirkara `MongoClient.connect` is slower but still you only need to run it once and you can use it wherever you want to. To simplify it just open 1 connection and use it without worry about connection speed/connection pool. That's why I suggested to use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) because it is more simplified in opening connections to database but cons of it is that you need prepared model of your documents.