# Nodejs HTTP server handling multiple requests inserting into DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http

I have an http server and every time it gets a post request, it is supposed to insert the data into MongoDB. This server is supposed to be constantly running and accepting thousands of request in any given second.

How can I maximize the efficiency and speed of my code? I feel like my current code is not fast enough and furthermore wastes CPU power when it makes a new db every time it receives a request.

**My current layout**

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

     req.on('data', function(chunk) {
          //Receive my data
     });

     req.on('end', function() {
          //JSON parse my data
          var db = new Db('test', new Server("111.111.11.111", 27017,{auto_reconnect: false}), {safe: true});  

          db.open(function(err, db) {
               //Insert data into DB
               db.close();
          });
     });
}); //End Http server
server.listen(8999);
```

I have tried replacing db.open with MongoClient.connect, but that considerably slows down processing and I don't know why. In this case, the older version of MongoDB Native for node js seems to work faster.

Comment: Just create the DB connection once and reuse it. It's designed to be resued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to shift to an approach where you open a large pool of connections during startup that are shared by your HTTP request handlers.  To tweak the MongoDB connection pool size to suit whatever scalability needs you have, pass an [`options`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect-options) parameter to your [`MongoClient.connect`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect) call.

```js
var options = {
    server: {
        // The number of pooled connection available to your app.
        poolSize: 100
    }
};

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://111.111.11.111/test', options, 
    function(err, db) {
        var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            // Your req.on calls go here, directly using db rather than creating
            // new instances. Don't close db either.
        });
        server.listen(8999);  
    }
);
```

Comment: What is the maximium pool size I can use?

Comment: @krikara It probably depends on your available memory and such.  1000 worked on my VM when I tried it just now, but 2000 errored out.

Comment: Okay, so let me confirm this : there is no `db.close`. When I run the program like this, it does save a lot of CPU (>50% of my original code), but it takes over twice as long as my original method. What exactly is going wrong here? Shouldn't this code make my server (receive data, parse json, insert into DB) a lot faster?

Comment: @krikara No `db.close`, and none of your other existing `db` related code either, for that matter.

Comment: Well forget everything I have previously said. Apparently, console.log(mydata) slowed everything down. After I deleted it, my server sped up over 100 times :S

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be better, but you can encapsulate that server inside the db, therefore persisting the connection:

```
var db = new Db('test', new Server("111.111.11.111", 27017,{auto_reconnect: false}), {safe: true});  

db.open(function(err, db) {
    var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        //now do stuff thru constant open connection
    });      
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: Currently, I am running jmeter to run httppost.js to send 300 requests to my server.js. It seems like encapsulating the server like this messes up the connection from my httppost.js and cannot finish the 300 requests.